# why there is two interface comparable and comparator in java for sorting the collections?

Tags: java, collections

why there is two interface comparable and comparator in java for sorting the collections?

both are doing the same task it seems... confusion on this sorting technique? Please advise

Comment: google before asking question. [difference between Comparable and Comparator](http://www.javatpoint.com/difference-between-comparable-and-comparator)

Comment: [A blog post regarding comparable and comparator](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/difference-between-comparator-and-comparable-in-java.html)

Comment: this is not for discussion, this is for solution so ask proper question please, 

check this http://www.programcreek.com/2011/12/examples-to-demonstrate-comparable-vs-comparator-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

One might want to sort given objects in other way then the it was defined in the given object (using `Comparable`), that's why there is `Comparator` available.

`Comparable` - used in given class to define the *default*/*natural ordering* sorting

`Comparator` - used by *foreign* code (e.g. from different library) to sort the data in different way, or to add sorting to class that doesn't define `Comparable`, or to add different sorting order (e.g. sometimes you might want to sort strings case insensitive and sometimes case sensitive).